# Serial link error and bad path jre 1.7.0_15 32-bi

Tags: java, path, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Trying to make an old java game run on the original PC both ca 2012.  JRE 1.7.0_15 (32bit) runs on linux (Puppy 6.3, 32 bit).  I can configure the game with java but the next console command to start the game fails with 
  **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-O" java.lang.Unsatisfied LinkError: no serial in java.library.path**

...and then more errors.

I don't know java or java syntax.  Can you tell from this info what I can type in urxvt console so it finds the serial link?  Java was installed clean with the Puppy Package Manager, although a few shared libraries report missing.  I found those files in other parts of code and online, but have no clue what to do with them so they're found properly or if that's even the problem.

Mine seems to be a common noob issue, but because I don't know what mounts and where, even the right command will fail without typing the true folder names and addresses which I don't have.  Can you tell from the error image?  Thank you.

[image: actual error first 3 lines]